# Probability of picking 4 right people out of 12

Tags: probability

There are 12 people with 12 unique zodiac signs. You start guessing each person's zodiac sign. What is the probability of you guessing **at least** 4 of them right?

@edit
You can't repeat your guess (you can only say "you are libra" once).

Comment: What strategy are you using for guessing?  If you guess libra for everyone then you'll get exactly one right every time.

Comment: Are you wanting the probability of *exactly* four?  Or *at least* four?  Have you ever heard of derangements or Recontres numbers?  And in case that question wasn't a strong enough hint... I'll rephrase this as:  **Hint:** think about derangements

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Yeah I want at least 4 of them

Comment: Well what I figured out so far was the possible placements of these people in the set. This is 12! - 8! = 11180. But I don't know if this is the right path tbh xd

Comment: $12!-8!$ is a pretty meaningless number in this problem... that is the number of arrangements of the twelve zodiac signs among the people such that very specifically the first four people are very specifically not the first four zodiac signs in their correct order.  I'll ask again.  Have you ever heard about derangements?  If you have, then my reminding you of their existence should be enough to get you back on the right track.  If you haven't, then you should go learn about them first and then revisit this problem because otherwise the solution won't make sense to you.

Comment: Probably somewhere in high school, a few years ago xd

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Okay so my initial thought was to count all the possibilities of these people arrangement. 
It's **12!**.
And basically I stuck here xd

Answer (score 1):

Remember, there are $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ distinct items in a row.

Remember further that you can decide a "correct order" to arrange them in (*for example, people from youngest to oldest, or star signs from January to December*).

Finally, remember that there are $!n$ ways to arrange those $n$ items in a row such that no item is in its "correct" spot where $!n$ is the Recontres number counting the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ objects.

---

To continue your problem, note that to have guessed exactly $k$ correct star-signs (*given that each person has a distinct star-sign and you guess each star-sign exactly once, etc...*) requires that you have guessed correctly $k$ star-signs for some subset of $k$ of the people while having guessed *incorrectly* for the remaining $n-k$ people.

> The probability of guessing exactly $k$ correct is then $\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}\cdot !(n-k)}{n!}$

Complete the problem, noting that to have guessed at least $4$ right involves guessing exactly $4$ right, or guessing exactly $5$ right, or ...  or alternatively not having guessed exactly $0$ right or exactly $1$ right etc...

Comment: Yooo, after like 2 hours i think i've grasped the idea behind of what you wrote.
I guess my problem was that I wasn't viewing this whole situation "globally" but each guess seperately.
So what it really means and correct me if i'm wrong:

it's the same situation as if I had a paper and six dice in a row, covered with cups with six different numbers on them.
I don't change the numbers I just change the order in a row.
The point is what is the probability of me writing numbers on a paper in the order so that at least say 4 of them will be in a correct position.